# How To Run win 10 From Internal Hard Drive (VirtualBox)(Fedora)

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, fedora

I have dual-boot win 10 & Fedora. I want to run the win 10 in Fedora using VirtualBox, how do I do this? I do not want to make an ISO of my OS like this. 
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-a-virtual-machine-image-of-your-existing-hard-drive-windows/

Edit: My dual boot looks like this [image]

partition 1 = win 10, partition 2 = Ubuntu, partition 3 = storage, partition 4 = Fedora
now how do I do virtual box directly from the partiton.
PS: I don't mind if I have to use `boxes` the Fedora VM app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is convert a physical machine (aka, your Windows 10 partition) to a VirtualBox VM. Sorry to repeat the task ahead of you, but using these terms I've come across [this helpful answer courtesy of Chris Hoffman of HowToGeek.](https://www.howtogeek.com/213145/how-to%C2%A0convert-a-physical-windows-or-linux-pc-to-a-virtual-machine/)

> For VirtualBox – A Manual Method
>
> VirtualBox doesn’t offer an easy graphical utility for converting a
>   physical machine to a virtual machine. If you’re feeling particularly
>   adventerous, they do offer some unsupported instructions for
>   converting a physical Windows computer to a VirtualBox virtual
>   machine. This requires some registry tweaking and shutting down the
>   computer. You’ll then have to manually create a copy of the disk and
>   convert it to a VirtualBox VDI file. The process for converting a
>   Linux virtual machine should be about the same, but without all the
>   extra tweaks required to make Windows behave. It’s much easier to move
>   Linux installations between different machines with different hardware
>   configurations.
>
> This process isn’t for the faint of heart, and we include it here only
>   for the sake of completeness. Even if you use VirtualBox already, you
>   may want to just use VMware or Microsoft’s utility and give VMware or
>   Hyper-V a try. If you’re still ready to give it a try, consult the
>   [MIgrate Windows page on VirtualBox’s wiki.](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows)

My personal belief, when faced with the above, is that imaging the existing Windows 10 partition/installation to VHD would be easiest and smoothest option available, as VirtualBox is 100% compatible with this format/standard, although of course this incurs the needed dataspace in which to store the exported image.

Comment: windows doesn't recognize hard drive format :-(